# Beamer: shadow whole frame

Tags: beamer, shading

I am trying to produce the following effect for a presentation of mine in beamer:

after the entire frame has been loaded, I would like to gray out / shadow the entire frame, and introduce an additional element (e.g., text) standing out in the center. I have looked around but found no discussion of any connected feature.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can "shadow" anything, including `beamer` frames, with a Ti*k*Z overlay picture.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Quack}
Hello
\pause
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\fill[gray!20,opacity=0.8] (current page.south west) rectangle 
(current page.north east);
\node at (current page.center) {Blub};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]